# Trying to bind enter key to a button

Tags: javascript, html

I have made a Cosmetic item calculatοr, it works fine functionality-wise but I want to add a feature that when I am pressing the enter key, it runs the calculation. Right now in the program I have to manually click on the "rechnen" button to calculate. Any ideas on what I can do to not always have to use the mouse to calculate?

I have tried using an Example from W3schools and implemented the code into mine but it doesn't seem to work.

```js
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 1.50;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 3.20;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.40;
var Einwegrasierer = 2;
var ZahnreinigunsBecher = 5;
var Mullkompressen = 6;

let Sum;

let WaschlotionAmount;
let HaarshampooAmount;
let BodylotionAmount;
let WundschutzcremeAmount;
let DeosprayAmount;
let ZahncremeAmount;
let ZahnbuersteAmount;
let ZahnspuellbecherAmount;
let ZahnhaftcremeAmount;
let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount;
let RasierklingenAmount;
let RasiererMitKlingenAmount;
let RasierschaumAmount;
let EinwegrasiererAmount;
let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount;
let MullkompressenAmount;

function Calculate() {
  if (Sum != 0) {
    Sum = 0;
  }
  let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value;
  let MullkompressenAmount = document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value;

  Sum = (Waschlotion * WaschlotionAmount) + (Haarshampoo * HaarshampooAmount) + (Bodylotion * BodylotionAmount) +
    (Wundschutzcreme * WundschutzcremeAmount) + (Deospray * DeosprayAmount) + (Zahncreme * ZahncremeAmount) +
    (Zahnbuerste * ZahnbuersteAmount) + (Zahnspuellbecher * ZahnspuellbecherAmount) + (Zahnhaftcreme * ZahnhaftcremeAmount) +
    (Zahnreinigunstabs * ZahnreinigunstabsAmount) + (Rasierklingen * RasierklingenAmount) + (RasiererMitKlingen * RasiererMitKlingenAmount) +
    (Rasierschaum * RasierschaumAmount) + (Einwegrasierer * EinwegrasiererAmount) + (ZahnreinigunsBecher * ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount) + (Mullkompressen * MullkompressenAmount);


  var roundedString = Sum.toFixed(2);
  var rounded = Number(roundedString);
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = rounded;

  var input = document.getElementById("Rechnen");
  Rechnen.addEventListener("keypress",
    function(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("Rechnen").click();
      }
    });
}



function ClearAll() {
  document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value = "";
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Rechnen {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
    <th>Menge</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Waschlotion</td>
    <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    <td> 1,30 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haarshampoo</td>
    <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    <td>1,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bodylotion</td>
    <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
    <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    <td>4,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Deospray</td>
    <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
    <td>1,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
    <td>1,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnbürste</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
    <td>1,25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
    <td>3,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
    <td>3,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
    <td>2,49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
    <td>4.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
    <td>1,40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><b id="Sum"></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="Rechnen" onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
  <button id="Clear All" onclick="ClearAll()">Clear All</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Wrap all the `input` elements in a single `form` then hook your JS to be triggered when the `submit` event of that `form` is fired and you will get this behaviour without need of any JS

Comment: Use a `from` element and use button `type=submit`. On the form element, prevent the default action.

Comment: You seem to be declaring a lot of variables (e.g. `WaschlotionAmount`) that are never actually used, since you re-declare them using `let` inside a function. You could either, remove the `let` inside the function so you are just assigning a value, or remove the pre-emptive variable declarations outside of the function to tidy up a bit.

Comment: It works, you just have to press 'tab' key(on a windows/linux PC) to bring the focus to the "rechnen" button and then press enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing one mistake. You are binding the keypress event with submit button. You should **bind it with the document**. And secondly just need to **move that code outside of calculate function**. It will work fine. Here is the updated code.

```js
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 1.50;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 3.20;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.40;
var Einwegrasierer = 2;
var ZahnreinigunsBecher = 5;
var Mullkompressen = 6;

let Sum;

let WaschlotionAmount;
let HaarshampooAmount;
let BodylotionAmount;
let WundschutzcremeAmount;
let DeosprayAmount;
let ZahncremeAmount;
let ZahnbuersteAmount;
let ZahnspuellbecherAmount;
let ZahnhaftcremeAmount;
let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount;
let RasierklingenAmount;
let RasiererMitKlingenAmount;
let RasierschaumAmount;
let EinwegrasiererAmount;
let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount;
let MullkompressenAmount;

function Calculate() {
  if (Sum != 0) {
    Sum = 0;
  }
  let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value;
  let MullkompressenAmount = document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value;

  Sum = (Waschlotion * WaschlotionAmount) + (Haarshampoo * HaarshampooAmount) + (Bodylotion * BodylotionAmount) +
    (Wundschutzcreme * WundschutzcremeAmount) + (Deospray * DeosprayAmount) + (Zahncreme * ZahncremeAmount) +
    (Zahnbuerste * ZahnbuersteAmount) + (Zahnspuellbecher * ZahnspuellbecherAmount) + (Zahnhaftcreme * ZahnhaftcremeAmount) +
    (Zahnreinigunstabs * ZahnreinigunstabsAmount) + (Rasierklingen * RasierklingenAmount) + (RasiererMitKlingen * RasiererMitKlingenAmount) +
    (Rasierschaum * RasierschaumAmount) + (Einwegrasierer * EinwegrasiererAmount) + (ZahnreinigunsBecher * ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount) + (Mullkompressen * MullkompressenAmount);


  var roundedString = Sum.toFixed(2);
  var rounded = Number(roundedString);
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = rounded;
}

  document.addEventListener("keypress",
    function(event) {

      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        Calculate();
      }
    });


function ClearAll() {
  document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value = "";
}
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Rechnen {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
    <th>Menge</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Waschlotion</td>
    <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    <td> 1,30 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haarshampoo</td>
    <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    <td>1,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bodylotion</td>
    <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
    <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    <td>4,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Deospray</td>
    <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
    <td>1,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
    <td>1,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnbürste</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
    <td>1,25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
    <td>3,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
    <td>3,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
    <td>2,49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
    <td>4.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
    <td>1,40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><b id="Sum"></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="Rechnen" onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
  <button id="Clear All" onclick="ClearAll()">Clear All</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you this was the most simple answer to implement :)

Answer (score 2):

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') Calculate()
})
```

```js
var Waschlotion = 1.30;
var Haarshampoo = 1.50;
var Bodylotion = 3;
var Wundschutzcreme = 4.80;
var Deospray = 1.80;
var Zahncreme = 1.50;
var Zahnbuerste = 1;
var Zahnspuellbecher = 1.25;
var Zahnhaftcreme = 3.20;
var Zahnreinigunstabs = 3.20;
var Rasierklingen = 2.49;
var RasiererMitKlingen = 4.50;
var Rasierschaum = 1.40;
var Einwegrasierer = 2;
var ZahnreinigunsBecher = 5;
var Mullkompressen = 6;

let Sum;

let WaschlotionAmount;
let HaarshampooAmount;
let BodylotionAmount;
let WundschutzcremeAmount;
let DeosprayAmount;
let ZahncremeAmount;
let ZahnbuersteAmount;
let ZahnspuellbecherAmount;
let ZahnhaftcremeAmount;
let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount;
let RasierklingenAmount;
let RasiererMitKlingenAmount;
let RasierschaumAmount;
let EinwegrasiererAmount;
let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount;
let MullkompressenAmount;

function Calculate() {
  if (Sum != 0) {
    Sum = 0;
  }
  let WaschlotionAmount = document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value;
  let HaarshampooAmount = document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value;
  let BodylotionAmount = document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value;
  let WundschutzcremeAmount = document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value;
  let DeosprayAmount = document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value;
  let ZahncremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnbuersteAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value;
  let ZahnspuellbecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value;
  let ZahnhaftcremeAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunstabsAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value;
  let RasierklingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value;
  let RasiererMitKlingenAmount = document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value;
  let RasierschaumAmount = document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value;
  let EinwegrasiererAmount = document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value;
  let ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount = document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value;
  let MullkompressenAmount = document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value;

  Sum = (Waschlotion * WaschlotionAmount) + (Haarshampoo * HaarshampooAmount) + (Bodylotion * BodylotionAmount) +
    (Wundschutzcreme * WundschutzcremeAmount) + (Deospray * DeosprayAmount) + (Zahncreme * ZahncremeAmount) +
    (Zahnbuerste * ZahnbuersteAmount) + (Zahnspuellbecher * ZahnspuellbecherAmount) + (Zahnhaftcreme * ZahnhaftcremeAmount) +
    (Zahnreinigunstabs * ZahnreinigunstabsAmount) + (Rasierklingen * RasierklingenAmount) + (RasiererMitKlingen * RasiererMitKlingenAmount) +
    (Rasierschaum * RasierschaumAmount) + (Einwegrasierer * EinwegrasiererAmount) + (ZahnreinigunsBecher * ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount) + (Mullkompressen * MullkompressenAmount);


  var roundedString = Sum.toFixed(2);
  var rounded = Number(roundedString);
  document.getElementById("Sum").innerHTML = rounded;

  var input = document.getElementById("Rechnen");
  Rechnen.addEventListener("keypress",
    function(event) {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("Rechnen").click();
      }
    });
}



function ClearAll() {
  document.getElementById("WaschlotionAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("HaarshampooAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("BodylotionAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("WundschutzcremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("DeosprayAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahncremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnbuersteAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnspuellbecherAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnhaftcremeAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunstabsAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasierklingenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasiererMitKlingenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("RasierschaumAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("EinwegrasiererAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("MullkompressenAmount").value = "";
  document.getElementById("ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount").value = "";
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') Calculate()
})
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Rechnen {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<table class="center">
  <tr>
    <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
    <th>Menge</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Waschlotion</td>
    <td><input id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
    <td> 1,30 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Haarshampoo</td>
    <td><input id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
    <td>1,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Bodylotion</td>
    <td><input id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
    <td><input id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
    <td>4,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Deospray</td>
    <td><input id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
    <td>1,80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahncreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
    <td>1,50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnbürste</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
    <td>1,25</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
    <td>3,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
    <td>3,20</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierklingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
    <td>2,49</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
    <td><input id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
    <td>4.50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Rasierschaum</td>
    <td><input id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
    <td>1,40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
    <td><input id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
    <td><input id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mullkompressen</td>
    <td><input id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
    <td><b id="Sum"></b></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="Rechnen" onclick="Calculate()">Rechnen</button>
  <button id="Clear All" onclick="ClearAll()">Clear All</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simplify this and use a form with a submit event. The submit will calculate and so will inputting anything.

I added a reset and changed the quantity field to type="number"

I am using

- [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [Array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // on page load
  const form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  const sumOutput = document.getElementById("Sum");
  const sumForm = () => {
    const sum = [...form.querySelectorAll("tbody tr")]
      .map(row => { // make an array of values
        let price = row.querySelectorAll("td")[2].textContent.trim() || 0;
        const qty = row.querySelector("input").value || 0;
        return price.replace(/,/, ".") * qty;
      })
      .reduce((a, b) => a + b); // sum the array
    sumOutput.innerHTML = sum.toFixed(2).replace(/\./,","); // replace the comma
  };
  form.addEventListener("input", sumForm); // delegating the input
  form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // stop submission - remove this if you want to submit too - possibly with a setTimeout
    sumForm();
  });
  form.addEventListener("reset", (e) => {
    sumOutput.innerHTML = "";
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
}

.center {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.buttons {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Rechnen {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <table class="center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Kosmetikartikel</th>
        <th>Menge</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Waschlotion</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="WaschlotionAmount"></td>
        <td> 1,30 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haarshampoo</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="HaarshampooAmount"></td>
        <td>1,50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bodylotion</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="BodylotionAmount"></td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Wundschutzcreme</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="WundschutzcremeAmount"></td>
        <td>4,80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Deospray</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="DeosprayAmount"></td>
        <td>1,80</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahncreme</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="ZahncremeAmount"></td>
        <td>1,50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahnbürste</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="ZahnbuersteAmount"></td>
        <td>1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahnspüllbecher</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="ZahnspuellbecherAmount"></td>
        <td>1,25</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahnhaftcreme</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="ZahnhaftcremeAmount"></td>
        <td>3,20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahnreinigunstabs</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="ZahnreinigunstabsAmount"></td>
        <td>3,20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rasierklingen</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="RasierklingenAmount"></td>
        <td>2,49</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rasierer mit Klingen</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="RasiererMitKlingenAmount"></td>
        <td>4.50</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rasierschaum</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="RasierschaumAmount"></td>
        <td>1,40</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Einwegrasierer</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="EinwegrasiererAmount"></td>
        <td>2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zahnreinigunsbecher</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="ZahnreinigunsBecherAmount"></td>
        <td>5</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mullkompressen</td>
        <td><input type="number" id="MullkompressenAmount"></td>
        <td>6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td><b>Gesamtpreis</b></td>
        <td><b id="Sum"></b></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button type="submit">Rechnen</button>
    <button type="reset">Clear All</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks that looks alot cleaner then what i made i will try it with how you used form and the function you made im a noob so ill have to study the function you made

Comment: I added some of the methods I use

Answer (score 0):

Add an EventListener to the keypress event and call the `Calculate' function when the key is enter.

To read more about EventListeners in JS: [W3 School about EventListener](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp)

Here is an example solution:

```
document.onkeypress = (e) => {
   e = e || window.event

   if(e.key === 'Enter'){
    Calculate()
   }
}
```